# How to compare LPCSTR

Tags: c++, compare, lpcstr

I have already tried strcmp and lstrcmp. I even tried to get do it with strlen but didn't work either, here is what I have

```
void check(LPCSTR lpText)
{
    if( strmp(lpText, "test") == 0)
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"equal", 0, 0); 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"not equal", 0, 0); 
    }
}
```

It always returns 1 no matter what, also charset in settings is set to Use Multi-Byte Character Set if it matters.

Comment: With standard substitutions made, works: http://ideone.com/oZdhiA

Comment: Yes, this setting you mention matters. Use uniformely MBCS or Unicode or know what you do when you mix.

Comment: thanks @0xC0000022L, I changed it back to unicode and lstrcmp works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try comparing it to a wide string literal if you're using wide strings:

```
if (lstrcmp(lpText, L"test") == 0) {
    // stuff
}
```

Edit: it seems that you were using the wrong character encoding.

Comment: It gives me this error: 'lstrcmpA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t [6]' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: @Furious: *don't* explicitly call the `*W` functions. Here you can also see why. Had you used `MessageBox` instead of `MessageBoxW` and defined `_UNICODE` globally in the preprocessor it would work out of the box as suggested by H2CO3! `lstrcmpW` of course also does the job when compiled without `_UNICODE`.

Comment: lpText declared LPCSTR.  It's in the parameter list.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guyz, my bad. Changed from MB to Unicode and now works.

Comment: @Furious, Multibyte is obsolete - don't use it unless you're dealing with an old codebase that's impossible to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for some learners like me.

If you use unicode setting, then `LPCTSTR` (here, 'T' means it varies according to UNICODE is defined or not) is `const wchar_t *`, so `wcscmp` can be used for comparing two `LPCTSTR`.

```
int wcscmp(
   const wchar_t *string1,
   const wchar_t *string2
);
```

E.g.,

```
// myStr is LPCTSTR
if (wcscmp(myStr, _T("mytext")) == 0) { // _T makes this to L"mytext" (if unicode).
  // myStr == "mytext"
}
```

(FYI, if not unicode, `LPCTSTR` is `const char*`)

Or, if you use `CString`(MFC project), then just `==` would work, which is equivalent to `CStringT::Compare`. It would automatically notice you're using UNICODE or not.

References(MSDN): [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/basic-cstring-operations?view=msvc-170#_core_comparing_cstring_objects) [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#compare) [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp)